# Gazebo Tutorial: Build error

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am going through the following tutorial [link](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=guided_i&tut=guided_i5) . Have been struggling with a build error at step 5. Below is the output of the compiler.

```
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/velodyne_plugin.dir/velodyne_plugin.cc.o                                                                                                                                     
/home/talha/techveda/gaz_tut/velodyne_plugin/velodyne_plugin.cc: In member function ‘virtual void gazebo::VelodynePlugin::Load(gazebo::physics::ModelPtr, sdf::ElementPtr)’:                                       
/home/talha/techveda/gaz_tut/velodyne_plugin/velodyne_plugin.cc:30:11: error: ‘class gazebo::VelodynePlugin’ has no member named ‘model’                                                                           
     this->model = _model;                                                                                                                                                                                         
           ^
/home/talha/techveda/gaz_tut/velodyne_plugin/velodyne_plugin.cc:34:11: error: ‘class gazebo::VelodynePlugin’ has no member named ‘joint’
     this->joint = _model->GetJoints()[0];
           ^
/home/talha/techveda/gaz_tut/velodyne_plugin/velodyne_plugin.cc:37:11: error: ‘class gazebo::VelodynePlugin’ has no member named ‘pid’
     this->pid = common::PID(0.1, 0, 0);
           ^
/home/talha/techveda/gaz_tut/velodyne_plugin/velodyne_plugin.cc:40:11: error: ‘class gazebo::VelodynePlugin’ has no member named ‘model’
     this->model->GetJointController()->SetVelocityPID(
           ^
/home/talha/techveda/gaz_tut/velodyne_plugin/velodyne_plugin.cc:41:13: error: ‘class gazebo::VelodynePlugin’ has no member named ‘joint’
       this->joint->GetScopedName(), this->pid);
             ^
/home/talha/techveda/gaz_tut/velodyne_plugin/velodyne_plugin.cc:41:43: error: ‘class gazebo::VelodynePlugin’ has no member named ‘pid’
       this->joint->GetScopedName(), this->pid);
                                           ^
/home/talha/techveda/gaz_tut/velodyne_plugin/velodyne_plugin.cc:45:11: error: ‘class gazebo::VelodynePlugin’ has no member named ‘model’
     this->model->GetJointController()->SetVelocityTarget(
           ^
/home/talha/techveda/gaz_tut/velodyne_plugin/velodyne_plugin.cc:46:13: error: ‘class gazebo::VelodynePlugin’ has no member named ‘joint’
       this->joint->GetScopedName(), 10.0);
             ^
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/velodyne_plugin.dir/velodyne_plugin.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/velodyne_plugin.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I am using the default CMake build script provided in the tutorial. Also i am running ubuntu 14.04 + gazebo 6.6.0 + GCC 4.8.4. I am not sure what i am doing wrong here, i have looked through gazebo plugins source code and pretty much every default plugin interface uses the same method. Also i do not have any other versions of gazebo installed on my machine for causing any version conflicts. I have sourced the setup files. Being a noob i'm a little out of depth here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13081/gazebo-tutorial:-build-error/) by [talha](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2559/talha/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-04-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-04-13**:
Maybe the tutorial is skipping some steps. Have you tried compiling the code under "Create an API" -> 4.?

**Comment by [talha](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2559/talha/) on 2016-04-13**:
Yes thank you. How stupid of me. The latter part of the tutorial includes the data members of the class. Although it is a bit misleading since it does instruct you to build the plugin without properly declaring all the required data members. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-04-13**:
Glad it works now, I ticketed an issue and added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It looks like the tutorial is incomplete, I ticketed an [issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_tutorials/issues/53/incomplete-code-in-intermediate-control) on `gazebo_tutorials`.

For now, skip to the code in "Create an API" -> 4.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0